# How to hard code the password in this script

Tags: linux, database, bash, shell, sh

i am very new to shell scripts and i found this code which will create or restore a db dump in mysql. but when i execute it it asks for the password for mysql. i want to hard code this password so i don't have to input it every time i am executing it.

the code:
    #!/bin/bash
    # A shell script to restore a large SQL dump using root login.
    # Usage: ./restore_dump.sh dump.sql app_devdb

```
(( $# != 2 )) && { echo "Usage: $0 dump.sql database_name"; exit 1; }
[ ! -f $1 ] && { echo "$1 not found1"; exit 1; }

RESULT=`mysql -u root -p --skip-column-names -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '$2'"`
if [ "$RESULT" != $2 ]; then
    echo "Database '$2' does not exist; creating it...";
    mysql -u root -p -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $2;"
    [ $? -ne 0 ] && { echo "Unknown error in attempting to create database '$2'"; exit 1; }
fi

(
  echo "SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;"
  echo "SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;"
  echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;"
  cat $1
  echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;"
  echo "SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=1;"
  echo "SET AUTOCOMMIT=1;"
  echo "COMMIT;"
) | mysql -o -u root -p "$2"
```

Comment: Please, check [4.6.6 mysql_config_editor — MySQL Configuration Utility](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are fine with hardcoding the password, you can simply provide it as an argument on the commandline.

For example:

`mysql -u root -pMYPASSWORD ...`

Comment: i actualy tried that but it gives me this error

`mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Database 'appdbssss' does not exist; creating it...
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: error is obvious your credentials are wrong. try to manually connect first without typing a script like `mysql -u root -pPASSWORD dbname`